# Javascript and images not working on github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

The files work perfectly on my PC but when I view it on Github Pages, both the images and Javascript do not seem to work at all.

The page link is: https://lupe-fiasnow.github.io/Industrious-Website/

The code is here: https://github.com/Lupe-FiaSnow/Industrious-Website

I'd appreciate any help as I just can't figure this problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base path of your site is `/Industrious-Website`, in your `index.html` you referenced:

```html
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

which will load https://lupe-fiasnow.github.io/main.js instead of https://lupe-fiasnow.github.io/Industrious-Website/main.js.

It should be (without the slash):

```html
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

The same apply for the `img` tag source :

```html
<img src="/img/person-3.jpg" alt="">
```

should be :

```html
<img src="img/person-3.jpg" alt="">
```

Also in your css file, you have :

```css
/* Showcase */
.showcase {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 55vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(244, 56, 56, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)),
    url(/img/skyline.jpg) center no-repeat;   <================== this line
  background-size: cover;
}
.info-mid{
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(244, 56, 56, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)),
    url(/img/skyline.jpg) center no-repeat fixed; <================== this line
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

`/img/skyline.jpg` will load https://lupe-fiasnow.github.io/img/skyline.jpg which doesn't exist, you want https://lupe-fiasnow.github.io/Industrious-Website/img/skyline.jpg. Update with `url(img/skyline.jpg)` would work